# Guzzle Post Request is Working Fine in Localhost but not working in server

Tags: php, yii2, guzzle

```
    $testHeader =  ['Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'accessToken' => 't46qds57zmoggo044oow4o4wgkkg8so', 'bankCode' => $_GET['bankCode']];

    $testData = json_encode(['amount' => '01','description' => 'Test','cardSeries' => '02cf03e89d6644e49c87510edceb96fc','bookingId' => '1', 'serviceType' => 'Flight']);

    $client = new HttpClient(['verify' => false]);
    $url = Url::to(['api/create-order'], true);

    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => $testHeader,
        'body' => $testData
    ]);

    $responseData = json_decode((string)$response->getBody())
```

I am sending guzzle post requesting. It working fine in localhost. but not working in server because body data is not getting send and   `if (Yii::$app->request->isPost)` this condition is failing.
i am receiving post data and header like this   `$header      = Yii::$app->request->getHeaders();`  `$body = Json::decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody(), false);`
body is returning null.

Comment: Did you check which value $url had when you are on the server?

Comment: I have same problem, work great in localhost but in server, header content-type change to "text/html" instead ''application/jason", i try force headers but without success